# Matlab updating subplots and hold on

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I am having trouble with updating subplots. I've boiled my problem down to the following example:

```
win = figure(1);
win.sub1 = subplot(2, 2, 1);
win.sub2 = subplot(2, 2, 2);
win.sub3 = subplot(2, 2, 3);
win.sub4 = subplot(2, 2, 4);

x = 1:1:10;

plot(win.sub2, x, x); %graphs the line y = x in the second subplot, good.
hold on;
plot(win.sub2, x, -x) %ought to plot line y = -x over line y = x, but does not.
```

When executing the second plot, the first plot disappears despite the hold on. The only thing that seems to make this work is if I use axes(win.sub2), but I'm trying to avoid that because it really slows down my program (plotting 4 subgraphs on one figure, each with about 2 overlaid plots, to create a 1000+ frame movie). I appreciate any assistance. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am a bit puzzled why your example does not work as expected, but changing `hold on;` to `hold(win.sub2, 'on');` seems to produce the desired result.

Note: when executing your example code, matlab gives me a warning, probably because the second line overwrites `win` as defined in the first line.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was not aware that hold was not simply applied to all axes...

Answer (score 2):

The problem seems to be that `hold on` does not affect the right axis. You can solve it using `set(...,'Nextplot','add')` on the intended axis. To do it sumultaneaously on all axes, it's much easier if `win` is an array instead of a struct. And by the way, line 1 is useless (`win` is overwritten).

So, the code would be:

```
win(1) = subplot(2, 2, 1);
win(2) = subplot(2, 2, 2);
win(3) = subplot(2, 2, 3);
win(4) = subplot(2, 2, 4);

set(win,'Nextplot','add') %// set this for all axes in variable win

x = 1:1:10;

plot(win(2), x, x); %graphs the line y = x in the second subplot, good.
plot(win(2), x, -x) %ought to plot line y = -x over line y = x, but does not.
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, and thanks for explaining that hold was not affecting the right axis. That insight was extremely valuable