# Matlab Subplot command not creating subplots

Tags: matlab, subplot

I am trying to get my data to form subplots, but the figure keeps overwriting instead of tiling into subplots as required.  Even when I post the very basic code found on the mathworks help site https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/subplot.html it replaces the figure instead of tiling.  For example, the super basic:

```
x = linspace(0,10);
y1 = sin(x);
y2 = sin(5*x);

figure
subplot(2,1,1);
plot(x,y1)

subplot(2,1,2);
plot(x,y2)
```

only produces one graph in the figure window.  Is there an option that I am missing?

Comment: it works for me, on matlab 2015a

Comment: Maybe you need a "hold on" command. You can [look at this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24247636/matlab-updating-subplots-and-hold-on). I hope it helps.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't help either.  "hold on" causes the two graphs to overlap in the same figure, but doesn't generate a separate subplot on the figure.

Comment: It might be that you have a variable called subplot which overrides the function. In this very basic example try to put a `clear all` at the beginning and see if it works.